# Spring Integration Inbound/Output adapter confluence

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

In my Spring integration project, I listen to incoming messages and send some requests from a server with TCP. I am using Spring integration version 5.2.21.

And the code block I am using is as follows.

```
 <int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="tcpClientFactory"
                                   type="client"
                                   host="${server.ip}"
                                   port="${server.port}"
                                   so-timeout="300000"
                                   so-keep-alive="true"
                                   single-use="false"
                                   using-nio="true"
                                   serializer="messageSerializer"
                                   deserializer="messageSerializer"/>

    <int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="outBoundChannelAdapter"
                                         connection-factory="tcpClientFactory"
                                         client-mode="true"
                                         auto-startup="true"
                                         retry-interval="30000"
                                         channel="toTcpAdapterChannel"/>

    <int-ip:tcp-inbound-channel-adapter id="inBoundChannelAdapter"
                                        connection-factory="tcpClientFactory"
                                        client-mode="false"
                                        auto-startup="true"
                                        channel="fromTcpGatewayChannel"/>
```

I have to manage all communication over a single connection upon request from the server. However, I see that my connection becomes unusable after a while and is taken again after the so-timeout period. Now I have a message coming in every minute.
And as long as I don't send any messages, I see that there is no problem with incoming messages.
However, when I send a message, I see that the incoming messages are no longer coming.
And after the so-timeout period has expired, I see that a new connection is made and the incoming messages are received again.

As I explained in the title, I think there is a problem due to the use of inbound and outbound adapters together. However, despite my research and many attempts, I could not find a solution.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: DEBUG logging should help you understand what is happening.